# FIlepicker upload_widget shows two button

Tags: file-upload, coffeescript, meteor

Hey I am a newbie on the `meteor` and currently trying to upload the image and I found `filepicker`.I have used jade-handlebars and coffeescript packages in my project.
Here is the code

test.coffee

```
FILEPICKER_APIKEY = 'Ay67d74M9SgadSy6uXJyu6'


Meteor.startup ->
  console.log 'test client'
  filepicker.setKey FILEPICKER_APIKEY  
  #filepicker.constructWidget document.getElementById "upload_widget"


Template.hello.greeting = ->
  "Hello World."

Template.hello.events
  'click input' : ->
    if console?
      console.log "You pressed the button"

Template.upload.rendered = ->
  filepicker.constructWidget this.find '#upload_widget'

Template.upload.events
  'change #upload_widget': (evt) ->
    if console?
      console.log JSON.stringify(evt.fpfile)
```

Here is the test.jade code

```
head
  title helloworld

body
  .container-fluid
    .span6
      {{> hello}}
    .span6
      {{> upload}}

template(name="hello")
  #test
    h1 Hello World!
  {{greeting}}
  input(type="button", value="Click")

template(name="upload")
  input(type="filepicker", id="upload_widget")
```

Now Here is my question:
There seems to appearing two filepick button. One button works fine and image can be uploaded and when pressing other button the `console` show the following error `uncaught exception: FilepickerException: API Key not found`
Why is the second button appearing ??
Please help me out to remove the second non-functional button.
ThankYou in advance!!